# Magento 2.4 product export not working for big data

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, export

I'm working on a magento 2.4 project which has more than 100000 products.The default magento export function for products is not working because of big data.Other exports are working fine.I have tried the product export without adding to the queue and directly creating the file.But it also failed.Any solution for this big data problem?Please help